# Put each JSON object and its item into <li> depending on how many objects there are

Tags: javascript, html, json

JSON (i got 3 a objects):

```
[{"NotificationID":13,
"SourceID":1,
"NotificationGroup":null,
"NotificationGroupID":0,
"NotificationName":"Updates",
"Description":"Server Maintenance",
"NotificationDate":"2017-01-01T00:00:00",
"DueDate":"2017-01-01T00:00:00",
"NotificationTo":"Me",
"ReadFlag":0,
"IsDelete":0,
"CreateDateTime":"2017-01-01T00:00:00",
"CreateBy":"Me",
"ModifyDateTime":"2017-01-01T00:00:00",
"ModifyBy":"Me",
"NotificationType":1,
"SourceName":"test"}]
```

OUTPUT should display the objects along with the object's item list

My JavaScript: Take note that ul tag and li tag havent been created

```
var notif = $.ajax({
    url: serviceApi,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var notifObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        var divElement = document.createElement("ul");
        var divElement_2 = document.createElement("li");

    },
});
```

Comment: use `Array.forEach`.

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` ? O.o

Comment: $.each(data, function(i, val) { ... }

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Array.forEach` inside success function.

```js
object = [{"NotificationID":13,
"SourceID":1,
"NotificationGroup":null,
"NotificationGroupID":0,
"NotificationName":"Updates",
"Description":"Server Maintenance",
"NotificationDate":"2017-01-01T00:00:00",
"DueDate":"2017-01-01T00:00:00",
"NotificationTo":"Me",
"ReadFlag":0,
"IsDelete":0,
"CreateDateTime":"2017-01-01T00:00:00",
"CreateBy":"Me",
"ModifyDateTime":"2017-01-01T00:00:00",
"ModifyBy":"Me",
"NotificationType":1,
"SourceName":"test"}];
object.forEach(function(obj){
 var divElement = document.createElement("ul");
document.body.appendChild(divElement);
for(x in obj){
 var divElement_2 = document.createElement("li");
 divElement_2.textContent = obj[x];
 divElement.appendChild(divElement_2);
};
 
});
```